# Syntax error(missing operator) in query expression when executing update query

Tags: delphi, ms-access, ado

I seem to have a problem with an Update query, I'm trying to use it to update a user's current details in a MS Access database using Delphi XE2. I asked a question previously and got help on the reserved word but now I seem to have another error with this query.
The error is :

```
Syntax error(missing operator) in query expression '?
Surname=?
Username=?
[Password]=?
Grade=?'
```

That is the error I keep getting
Below is the coding I have done:

```
procedure TUser.UpdateUser(pFirstname, pSurname, pUsername,
  pPassword: String; pGrade, pID: Integer);
var
  sSQL : String;
begin
  opendb('QuizDB.mdb');

  DB.Close;
  DB.SQL.Add('UPDATE tblUsers SET');
  DB.SQL.Add('Firstname=:Firstname');
  DB.SQL.Add('Surname=:Surname');
  DB.SQL.Add('Username=:Username');
  DB.SQL.Add('[Password]=:Password');
  DB.SQL.Add('Grade=:Grade');
  DB.SQL.Add('WHERE ID=:ID');

  Db.Parameters.ParamByName('Firstname').Value := pFirstname;
  Db.Parameters.ParamByName('Surname').Value := pSurname;
  Db.Parameters.ParamByName('Username').Value := pUsername;
  Db.Parameters.ParamByName('Password').Value := pPassword;
  Db.Parameters.ParamByName('Grade').Value := pGrade;
  DB.Parameters.ParamByName('ID').Value := pID;
  DB.ExecSQL;
end;
```

Where DB is an ADOQuery component, ID is the primary Key in the database and unique to each record. TUser is my class I have created as a object.

Please Help me sort this out.

Comment: Have you seen this: [http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html) and comma delimiter?

Comment: MySQL is not the same as MS Access. Please use the tags that are appropriate to your question instead of just adding anything that is similar. It helps properly organize the questions, and makes their presence known to people who might help you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

please use Comma in SQL add lines:

```
DB.Close;
DB.SQL.Add('UPDATE tblUsers SET');
DB.SQL.Add('Firstname=:Firstname,');
DB.SQL.Add('Surname=:Surname,');
DB.SQL.Add('Username=:Username,');
DB.SQL.Add('[Password]=:Password,');
DB.SQL.Add('Grade=:Grade');
DB.SQL.Add('WHERE ID=:ID');
```

Comment: @Alladinianת I think he got the right answer here. a sample would be nice thought.

Comment: @Alladinian thx for warning, but it is the answer... I ll just be care about include a code block for the be a sample of subject..

Comment: @kobik thanks for editing. I'll be carefull answering like this kind in future.

Comment: @kobik I guess it's fine now so I have removed the comment, thanx for the heads up